# C# compiler options - embedding manifest file

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, manifest

I have found that it is possible to embedd manifest file (added to resources) with Compiler option /win32manifest. I am trying to find compiler options in VS express but I cannot see it. Could you please help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have Express handy to check this.  But it is not a build option in the retail edition, you add a manifest with Project + Add New Item, Application Manifest File.  If you don't see it in the list of item templates, you can add it by hand after building with the mt.exe tool from the Windows SDK.  Get basic command line syntax help with mt.exe /?  You'll need to use resource ID #1 for a .exe.

Beware that VS2008 already adds a manifest to keep the .exe compatible with Vista UAC.  Your replacement manifest should contain the `<requestedExecutionLevel>` element.

Comment: I thought in VS2008 there is no need for using mt. It should embed the custom manifest automatically when selected in the project properties.